# Error running SPARQL query with FILTER and LIMIT

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/ and running a SPARQL query using a FILTER, ORDER BY and LIMIT. Here is the query - it's supposed to return a sample of people and their names and birth dates:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?x0 ?name ?dob WHERE {
  ?x0 rdf:type foaf:Person.
  ?x0 rdfs:label ?name.
  ?x0 dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?dob.
  FILTER REGEX(?name,"[A-Z].*").
} ORDER BY ?name LIMIT 100
```

When I run the query it returns an internal error:

```
Virtuoso VECSL Error VECSL: Internal error, ssl refd before set, please report query to support
SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-unconnected-variables 1 define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?x0 ?name ?dob
WHERE {
?x0 rdf:type foaf:Person.
?x0 rdfs:label ?name.
?x0 dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?dob.
FILTER REGEX(?name,"[A-Z].*").
} ORDER BY ?name LIMIT 100
```

but if I comment out my FILTER using # the query runs OK. Has anyone seen this before? Is there an obscure error in my SPARQL or is it an internal error in the endpoint?

Comment: Given that it works on Virtuoso 7.x (run your query [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparq)), it's clearly a bug in Virtuoso 8.x - please report this issue to the Virtuoso devs.

Comment: I was using http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/ instead of http://dbpedia.org/sparq as the latter was returning duplicate dates of birth and was not so up-to-date! So I have to choose between duplicate dates and a buggier new version of Virtuoso?

Comment: Also I will try and figure out how to report the bug, but I'm not familiar with Virtuoso, other than running the SPARQL endpoints.

Comment: You always have the opportunity to load DBpedia into a local triple store of your choice. Clearly, the date literal issues are contained in the RDF dump, thus, you'd have to do some data cleaning in advance, i.e. before loading. I also did this some time ago, a bunch of regex patterns via `sed`

Comment: I am learning the basics of SPARQL, therefore loading DBpedia into a local store is way beyond my experience. I originally wanted to extract useful data from DBpedia and use it to progress another project I'm working on.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Virtuoso 8 doesnt support a query that involves an `ORDER BY` and a `FILTER`.

This issue has been reported since June 2017.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you provide a prooflink? BTW, after replacing e. g. `ORDER BY ?name` with `ORDER BY ?dob`, the query works fine (as it seems).

Comment: The issue about the `FILTER + regex` has been reported back in the year. I need to retrieve the mailing list that specifies the reporting. The combo `ORDER + FILTER` is only my statement. What surprise me is the security error. Misspelling is common thing but security issue from Virtuoso...

Comment: *What surprise me is the security error* — I suppose `ssl` is rather  "state slot" than "secure sockets layer" :)

Comment: Oh my.. Obviously. Thank you

Comment: Being the consensus is it's a bug, and it's been known of for 11 months, is there any work around?

Comment: Sadly, no evidence of it.

Comment: @Ubercoder, something like `FILTER REGEX(?name,"[A-Z].*").
  BIND (str(?name) AS ?name_)
} ORDER BY ?name_ LIMIT 10` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on everyone's help the answer is:

1. The Virtuoso end-point that hosts http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/ has a bug affecting FILTER and ORDER BY.
2. A work-around is possible.

Code:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?x0 ?name2 ?dob WHERE {
  ?x0 rdf:type foaf:Person.
  ?x0 rdfs:label ?name.
  ?x0 dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?dob.
  FILTER REGEX(?name,"^[A-Z].*").
  BIND (str(?name) AS ?name2)
} ORDER BY ?name2 LIMIT 100
```

Basically it does a BIND and does the ordering and the limit on the new bound variable.